# How to generate random 3D shapes (using generalized cylinders)

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, computational-geometry

I am trying to generate videos of random shapes following controlled transformations in 3 dimensions (rigid body transformations for now).
I want a large variety of shapes but I am not constrained on the underlying model. I would prefer to use python because I am more familiar with it but if it makes things much simpler another language could work too.

I tried to do that using python and numpy but triangulation does not seem to work. 
I defined a curve `crv` and circles `bc` with random diameters such that the circles are placed at regular intervals around the curve.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.tri as mtri

from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def angle(v1,v2):
    av1 = np.sqrt((v1**2).sum(-1))
    av2 = np.sqrt((v2**2).sum(-1))
    v12 = np.dot(v1,v2.T)
    return (np.arccos(v12/(av1*av2)))

def rotation_matrix(axis, theta):
    """
    Return the rotation matrix associated with counterclockwise rotation about
    the given axis by theta radians.
    """
    axis = np.asarray(axis)
    theta = np.asarray(theta)
    axis = axis/np.sqrt(np.dot(axis, axis))
    a = np.cos(theta/2)
    b, c, d = -axis*np.sin(theta/2)
    aa, bb, cc, dd = a*a, b*b, c*c, d*d
    bc, ad, ac, ab, bd, cd = b*c, a*d, a*c, a*b, b*d, c*d
    return np.array([[aa+bb-cc-dd, 2*(bc+ad), 2*(bd-ac)],
                     [2*(bc-ad), aa+cc-bb-dd, 2*(cd+ab)],
                     [2*(bd+ac), 2*(cd-ab), aa+dd-bb-cc]])

CP=100
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
theta = np.linspace(-4 * np.pi, 4 * np.pi, CP)
crv = np.zeros((CP,3))
crv[:,2] = np.linspace(-2, 2, CP)
r = crv[:,2]**2 + 1
crv[:,0] = r * np.sin(theta)
crv[:,1] = r * np.cos(theta)


v1=np.array([0,0,1])[None,:]
v2s=np.diff(crv,axis=0)
ax12=np.cross(v1,v2s)
thetas=angle(v1,v2s).T

#Base circle
CiP=400
phi = np.linspace(0.0,2*np.pi,CiP)
r = np.random.rand(CiP)*0.4
bc = np.zeros((CiP,3))
bc[:,0] = r*np.cos(phi)
bc[:,1] = r*np.sin(phi)

points= np.zeros((v2s.shape[0],CiP,3))

for i in range(v2s.shape[0]):
    # Rotation matrix to align the base circle and the direction of the curve 
    rm1 = rotation_matrix(ax12[i,:],thetas[i,:])
    # This is an attempt to fine tune the alignment 
    rm2 = rotation_matrix(v2s[i,:], theta[i]/8.)
    # Rotate bc and center it to the curve.
    points[i,:,:]=np.dot(rm2.squeeze(), np.dot(rm1.squeeze(),bc.T)).T + crv[i]



ax.plot_trisurf(points[:,:,0].ravel(),points[:,:,1].ravel(),points[:,:,2].ravel())
plt.show()
```

So far my approach doesn't seem to work.

Can you help me fix this?

Do you know a better way to do this?

Please, keep in mind that it is supposed to work with random curves not a fixed one as in the above example. In fact generalized cylinders are not necessary at all but rather something that is capable of generating a large diversity of random structured shapes.

Thank you!